# Getting unwanted rows with LIKE in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm back again, and it's another school topic

I'm restricted to the Commands WHERE FROM SELECT

The subject is basically show the name from table customers beginning with A or B and ending with S or P, i've tried multiple OR solutions but none of them seem to work, the answer is 1 column 6 rows
i can't get this code to work

```
USE Northwind
SELECT
CompanyName
FROM Customers
WHERE CompanyName LIKE '[A/B]%' or CompanyName LIKE '%[S/P]'
go
```

With this code i get 31 rows :/

Comment: Sorry, MYSQL was not supposed to be there

Comment: I'm not super familiar with `LIKE` expressions, but shouldn't it be `[AB]%`, not `[A/B]%`?

Comment: If it's AB it has to begin with AB, i want it to start with A or B

Comment: "`[]` - Any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set ([abcdef])." -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: That would work on AB but not on the SP part, you need to divide S and P apart, thanks for the link though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about combining together:

```
SELECT
CompanyName
FROM Customers
WHERE CompanyName LIKE '[A/B]%[S/P]'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57d59/1)

Comment: I solved it with changing OR to and, but this seems to shorten the code, thanks for the idea

Comment: @MertDemirsü -- using `and` will work just fine, but this would probably be the best method.

Comment: Yes, this is shorter and clearer, therefore better.  As per @Matthew Haugen in the comments, it appears you also do not need any separate between the match characters.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should accomplish what you want:

```
SELECT CompanyName
FROM Customers
WHERE 
    (LEFT(CompanyName,1) = "A" OR LEFT(CompanyName,1) = "B")
    AND (RIGHT(CompanyName,1) = "S" OR RIGHT(CompanyName,1) = "P")
```